# Take specific word from SQL output

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to print a specific word from the string as a new column output:

Query

```
SELECT Sentences From form where Date > '2020-04-01';
```

Output

```
Sentences    
Hello my name is Mark, 458796 available.
Hello my name is Dan, 4581 available.
Hello my name is Steven, Steven unnavailable.
```

I was wondering if is possible in Query above, add a condition so the output will look like

```
Sentences                                           Test 
Hello my name is Mark, 458796 available.            458796 
Hello my name is Dan, 4581 available.               4581 
Hello my name is Steven, Steven unavailable.        Steven
```

Basically, I need to get every 6th work from string for each row.

I was trying to use `SUBSTRING([dbo].[Sentences]` but it doesn't work as words doesn't have the same number of characters.

I use a SQL Server database.

Comment: Tag the DBMS you use.

Comment: @stickybit I use Sql server.. MSSQL

Comment: SQL Server has a bunch of string functions which will allow you to accomplish this - have a go and let us know how you get on.

Comment: Not clear... are you looking for the nth word or first word after the comma ?

Comment: @JohnCappelletti I am looking for nth word. In this case would be 6th word

Comment: Can you define _word_? How many words is "state-of-the-art"?

Comment: @HABO word all words between empty space.

Comment: In "Hello my name is Dan, 4581 available." you're saying "Hello" and "available." aren't words because they aren't _between_ empty space, but "Dan," is a word. So there is no "6th work", just five?

Answer (score 2):

Using a bit of JSON.

Note that the `[key]` begins with an index of `0`

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([Sentences] varchar(50))  Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 ('Hello my name is Mark, 458796 available.')
,('Hello my name is Dan, 4581 available.')
,('Hello my name is Steven, Steven unnavailable.')
 
Select * 
 From  @YourTable A
 Cross Apply (
                Select Value
                 From  OpenJSON( '["'+replace(replace([Sentences],'"','\"'),' ','","')+'"]' )
                 Where [Key]+1 = 6
             ) B
```

**Results**

```
Sentences                                       Value
Hello my name is Mark, 458796 available.        458796
Hello my name is Dan, 4581 available.           4581
Hello my name is Steven, Steven unnavailable.   Steven
```

**EDIT** - With a bit of string manipulation, you can forgo the `CROSS APPLY` and `OpenJSON`

```
Declare @Word int = 6
Select * 
      ,Value = JSON_VALUE('["'+replace(replace([Sentences],'"','\"'),' ','","')+'"]',concat('$[',@Word-1,']') )
 From  @YourTable A
```